# Removing text from output in Powershell

Tags: powershell, printers

I am trying to remove part of the text that is returned from `get-wmiobject`, the text I am trying to remove is `@{ShareName=PRT47}` and I only want the printer name that is returned so the suffix if you will.

I have tried different by attempting to get the number of characters and delete them but I have since found out that you can also use what is in the proceeding cmdlet.

[Remove Text](http://newdelhipowershellusergroup.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/part-2-text-manipulation-in-powershell.html)

```
   $text  =  Get-WmiObject -Class $class -Filter Network=True | Select ShareName | Where-Object {$_ -   like "*PRT*"} 
    ForEach ($shareName in $text) { 
    $newprinter = "\\$newserver\$shares"
    rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n $newprinter
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use -replace to find and replace strings with blank entries.  Using your example of @{ShareName=PRT47}

```
$text = $text -replace '(.*)=(.*)' ${2}
echo $text //Prints PRT47}
```

An alternative is to use split. The below example will split on each equal sign.

```
$text = $text -split '='
echo $text[0] //prints @{ShareName
echo $text[1] //prints PRT47}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside ForEach, specify the shareName property like this.

```
ForEach ($shareName in $text) { 

 $shareName.sharename

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it if you have Powershell 3.0 or higher:

```
$text  =  (Get-WmiObject -Class $class -Filter Network=True).ShareName | Where-Object {$_ -like "*PRT*"}
```

Or, closer to Hysh_00's suggestion if you only have Powershell 2.0:

```
$text  =  Get-WmiObject -Class $class -Filter Network=True | foreach {$_.ShareName | Where-Object {$_ -like "*PRT*"}}
```